# Do I need to ask visa again though I have a visa which is still in charge?

Tags: visas, singapore

I have been visited Singapore with that visa but the visa is for multilpe journeys.

Comment: I assume that by "in charge" you mean it's still valid ?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a valid, unexpired visa for Singapore which is multiple entry, you can use it for multiple visits, until the day of its expiration. You do not need to obtain a new visa until after your existing visa expires.

Note that, like the US and unlike many other countries, Singapore visas' expiration date is the last date which you may *enter* the country. It is *not* the date which you must leave. That will be stamped into your passport by immigration officials.

[From the Immigration & Checkpoints Authority](http://www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=252&secid=165):

> A holder of a valid Singapore visa who is found suitable for entry into Singapore will be issued with an immigration pass to enter and remain in Singapore.   You are advised to check your passport for the arrival visit pass endorsement when in Singapore and take note of the period of stay granted before leaving the checkpoint.  The period of stay granted is shown on the visit pass endorsement given on your passport and it is not tied to the validity of your visa.

Comment: Huh, interesting. Didn't know that about US visa expiry dates

Comment: @blackbird57 See [here](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/visa-expiration-date.html) if you're interested in all the details on US visa validity.