# UK Visa expiry on 8th Jan and travel is on 4th Jan for 3 weeks

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

I'm planning to travel on Jan 4th 2016 for 3 wekes and my 6 months visa will expire on Jan 8 is it fine to travel? I am from India..

Comment: Why do you think that the UK Border agency will allow you to stay beyond the expiry of your visa ?

Comment: Some countries like USA, you can enter if you have a valid visa and stay will be decided by POE and you can stay as per your I-94.\

Comment: Does USA allow you to stay in US on an expired visa ?? Isn't that a loophole for illegal immigration ?

Comment: No, as per USA immigration rules, visa is required to entry the country and immigration officer will determine how long you can stay based on  your invite/visa type

Comment: `immigration officer will determine how long you can stay` That is wrong. Immigration officer decided whether you can enter the country or not. I am talking about the border official at the airport. If he(she) presumes you would overstay or are an illegal immigrant or are trying to fool him(her), he will deny entry.

Comment: that is there but visa is for only entry for USA and immigration office will decide about your stay

Comment: @DumbCoder US visa validity dates are [the dates which you may _enter_ the country](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/41942/3221). You can remain in the country for the duration on your immigration stamp, even if it is past the expiration date of the visa. Singapore visas [also work this way](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/58306/3221). But it's not very common.

Comment: @DumbCoder there is a reason the US border stamp has a blank for "admitted until"; the notation in that spot can be a date before *or after* the visa expiration date.  (It can also say "d/s," meaning "duration of status."  This applies only to certain categories of visa, such as student visas.)  The decision as to what date to write rests with the border official at the airport or other port of entry.

Answer (score 3):

Your last day of stay in UK must not be later then the expiration date of your visa. You will need a new visa if you want to stay more than 4 days, considering travel and visa expiration dates. More detailed info can be found [on the UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration).

Comment: You might want to quote the relevant content from the link. Links are prone to 404-oblivion.